# Which of the classifications and different ways of expressing is correct?

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

I know that uncertainty in measurement is different from measurement error ([1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/796108/what-is-the-difference-between-error-and-uncertainty/796199#796199)).

But when it comes to classification (of uncertainty and error) and different ways of expressing uncertainty and error in measurement, it kind of feels the same.

Like,

**TYPES OF ERRORS**

> 1. Systematic errors
> 2. Random errors
>    ([source](https://www.webassign.net/question_assets/unccolphysmechl1/measurements/manual.html)).
>    same as in [2](https://unacademy.com/content/upsc/study-material/mathematics/classification-of-measurement-errors/), [3](https://byjus.com/physics/accuracy-precision-error-measurement/), [4](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/errors-in-measurement/), [5](https://www.scribbr.com/methodology/random-vs-systematic-error/), [6](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/students-guide-to-data-and-error-analysis/errors-classification-and-propagation/9FFB338AE5F498F6F4B5ABD145AD44BF).

**Types of Uncertainty**

> Uncertainties can be divided into two different types: systematic uncertainties and random (statistical) uncertainties.
> ([Source](https://www.physics.columbia.edu/sites/default/files/content/Lab%20Resources/Lab%20Guide%201_%20Introduction%20to%20Error%20and%20Uncertainty.pdf#:%7E:text=Uncertainties%20can%20be%20divided%20into%20two%20di,erent%20types%3A%20systematic%20uncertainties%20and%20random%20%28statistical%29%20uncertainties2.))

**Different ways of expressing error in a measurement.**

> Different measures of errors include:
>
> **Absolute Error**
>
> **Percent Error**
>
> **Relative Error**
> ([source](https://byjus.com/physics/accuracy-precision-error-measurement/))
> same as in [7](https://testbook.com/physics/errors-in-measurements), [8](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/errors-in-measurement/).

**Different ways of expressing Uncertainty in measurement**

> **Absolute uncertainty**
>
> **Fractional uncertainty**
>
> **Percent uncertainty**
> ([source](https://file:///C:/Users/welcome/Downloads/MicrosoftEdgeDropFiles/Default/Experimental-Uncertainty1.pdf)). Same as in [9](https://www.physics.columbia.edu/sites/default/files/content/Lab%20Resources/Lab%20Guide%201_%20Introduction%20to%20Error%20and%20Uncertainty.pdf#:%7E:text=Uncertainties%20can%20be%20divided%20into%20two%20di,erent%20types%3A%20systematic%20uncertainties%20and%20random%20%28statistical%29%20uncertainties2.), [10](https://www.bellevuecollege.edu/physics/resources/measure-sigfigsintro/f-uncert-percent/).

**Question:** Now, I don't know which of the above classifications and different ways of expressing is correct.

Are all of the above classifications and different ways of expressing is correct or only some of those are correct?

Comment: They are all correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How uncertainties and errors are expressed and classified depends on context and convention. Your listing is correct and more than sufficient for student physics measurements, but there are multiple classification schemes that you might eventually encounter.

**Expression**

It is best to express uncertainty and error in the way that is most immediately convenient and useful, but with sufficient information to allow conversion into other forms.  For example, the current absolute uncertainty on the [Gravitational Constant G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) is $0.00015\times10^{-11}\,\mathrm{N\,m^2/kg^2}$. As long as I know that the current measured value is $6.67430\times10^{-11}\,\mathrm{N\,m^2/kg^2}$, I can also express the relative uncertainty as a fraction ($2.2\times10^{-5}$), a percentage ($0.0022\%$), or in parts-per-million ($22$ ppm).

Expressions of error are always comparisons between two measurements or measurement and theory, and such differences are often expressed in terms of the uncertainty $\sigma$. For example, the ["Hubble Tension"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law#Hubble_tension) is well known disagreement in the values of the [Hubble Constant](https://www.britannica.com/science/Hubble-constant), where the value determined from the local [Cosmic distance ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_distance_ladder) [disagrees](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2302.05709) by $4-6\,\sigma$ from the value determined from the [Cosmic Microwave Background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background).

**Classification**

There are multiple ways to classify uncertainty. You likely only need to know about statistical/systematic for now, but it may be worth being aware of the existence of a few other schemes, especially Type A/B.

*Statistical/Systematic*

Classifies uncertainties by how they scale with how much data is collected:

- Statistical ($\sigma_\mathrm{stat}$): uncertainties that keep getting smaller as long as you keep taking more of the same data, typically being proportional to the inverse square root of the amount of data.
- Systematic ($\sigma_\mathrm{sys}$): uncertainties that don't keep getting smaller by simply taking more of the same data.

Classification into Statistical and Systematic uncertainties is useful when combining measurements from different experiments and also when deciding how long to run an experiment.
It is not usually worth taking more data once $\sigma_\mathrm{stat}<<\sigma_\mathrm{sys}$. One exception to this is if the largest contributor to $\sigma_\mathrm{sys}$ is an theoretical uncertainty $\sigma_\mathrm{th}$, and it is expected that theorists might be able to reduce this uncertainty in the near future.

*Type A/B*

Classifies uncertainties by how they are evaluated:

- Type A: uncertainties evaluated by a statistical analysis of measured values
- Type B: uncertainties that are not Type A

Although statistical and systematic uncertainties are the preferred classifications in most areas of physics, Type A/B is now common in [metrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrology) and related areas of technology and engineering.
If you want a more rigorous introduction, the definitive resource is the ["Guide to the Expression of Uncertainty in Measurement (GUM)"](https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/2071204/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf/cb0ef43f-baa5-11cf-3f85-4dcd86f77bd6?version=1.12&t=1696944486074&download=true) and its [supplements](https://www.bipm.org/en/committees/jc/jcgm/publications) from the [Joint Committee for Guides in Metrology (JCGM)](https://www.bipm.org/en/committees/jc/jcgm).

*Aleatory/Epistemic/Ontological*

Classifies uncertainties by the [knowledge used to model the system](https://analystsuncertaintytoolkit.github.io/UncertaintyWeb/index.html):

- Aleatory ("knowns"): uncertainties modelled by known inherent randomness in the system.
- Epistemic ("known-unknowns"): uncertainties due to things we know we don't know, e.g. lack of knowledge about the values of known model parameters.
- Ontological ("unknown unknowns"): uncertainties due to things we don't know we don't know, which cause errors in our model that we are unaware of.

I don't think I've ever seen these classifications applied to specific measurement uncertainties in physics, so you can ignore them for now. They are, however, relative common in fields such as medical research and risk analysis, or in more philosophical discussions of uncertainty.

Answer (score 2):

Let me tell you one more way to interpret error and uncertainty: Error is the difference between the true value and the measured value. Uncertainty is the reported value that lies within the range of values within which the true value is asserted to lie in.

[This article](https://www.physics.columbia.edu/sites/default/files/content/Lab%20Resources/Lab%20Guide%201_%20Introduction%20to%20Error%20and%20Uncertainty.pdf) covers definitions as well as classification in detail. The classification you have provided is flawless.

There can be many ways to say the same thing while the essence remains unchanged parameters may change. If uncertainty of a
measurement obtainable by a tool is known we can tell the range within which true value will lie, if error obtained in measurement is known we can tell how much the obtained value deviates from true value; here is a good illustration:

[image: uncertainty vs error]

Comment: *Uncertainty is the reported value that lies within the range of values within which the true value is asserted to lie in.* I'm having a hard time parsing this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The term **error** is used in the context of *theoretical models*, while the term **uncertainty** is used to describe *real measurements*. They describe related, but different quantities. In short:

1. The error is defined by $\epsilon = y_{meas}-y_{true}$. Thus, it is a deviation.
2. The uncertainty of the measurement $y_{meas}$ is $Sd[y_{meas}]$. It's a standard deviation.

### Explanation

In **statistics**, the standard model of a measurement device is
$$
Y_{meas} = y_{true} + \epsilon
\tag{1}
$$
Here the $\epsilon$ is the **error**. Usually we assumed that it is normally distributed, $\epsilon\sim N(\mu_\epsilon, \sigma_\epsilon)$, and the systematic offset (bias) vanishes, $\mu_\epsilon=0$. As you said yourself, the error $\epsilon$ is the difference between the measured value and the true value -- see first item in the list above. However, the model (1) is theoretical. Therefore, also the error is a theoretical quantity, which we are unable to access in practice. In statistics there is  the famous quote: "All models are wrong, but some are useful".

In practice we do not know $y_{true}$, and thus we will never know the error $\epsilon$. Thus, the best we can do is to take repeated measurements ${\bf Y}_{meas}=\{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n\}$. If eq. (1) is (approximately) true, and if we take sufficient many measurements, we obtain two estimates (I use "hats" to distinguish between the model parameter and its estimate):

1. Estimate of the true value $\hat y_{true} = E[{\bf Y}]$, which is not of interest in this question, and,
2. Estimate of the **uncertainty of the measurement**
   $$
   Sd[{\bf Y}_{meas}] 
   = Sd[{\bf Y}_{true} + {\bf \epsilon}]
   = Sd[{\bf \epsilon}]
   = \hat \sigma_{\epsilon} 
   $$
   This is the second item in the list above.

Thus, note that the error is the unknown quantity $\epsilon$, while the uncertainty of the measurement is the estimated quantity $\hat \sigma_{\epsilon}$. These are different things -- probably it's most explicit that these are different things by restating the model assumption $\epsilon \sim N(\mu_\epsilon, \sigma_\epsilon)$: The epsilon is a random variable, while $\sigma_\epsilon$ is a parameter of the model.

**Side remark:** The *residuals* are usually defined by
$$res = y_{meas} - \hat y_{true}$$
Thus, the residual $res$ is similar to the error $\epsilon$, but instead of using the (unknown) true value $y_{true}$, we the known estimate $\hat y_{true}$.

Although you stated in your question that you are aware of the difference between *error* and *uncertainty of a measurement*, I elaborated on this difference, because I felt that you were not aware in which context we refer to *error* and in which context we refer to *uncertainty*. Understanding the context helps you to distinguish between $\epsilon$ and $\hat \sigma_{\epsilon}$.
Furthermore, usually it is clear from the context if somebody refers to $\epsilon$ or $\hat \sigma_{\epsilon}$ even if he/she uses the formally "wrong" term (error/uncertainty) -- and believe me, there are tons of references, which use the "wrong" term, so we need to be able to understand why these authors want to tell us.

So **formally**, if we refer to ...

- the theoretical parameter $\epsilon$, we should use the term *error*.
- the theoretical parameter $\sigma_\epsilon$, we should use term *uncertainty* of $y_{meas}$.
- the result of our experiment $\hat \sigma_\epsilon$, we should  use term *estimate of the uncertainty* of $y_{meas}$.

Finally, a word of caution: The definitions I used above are common in the field of statistics, which is a branch of mathematics.  I reckon that in physics there exists text books, which define these terms differently. Thus, the best we can do is use one method in our own publications, and to be open minded. As said before, usually the context describes rather well what the author tries to express. In addition, in my own publications I usually try to be very explicit by stating the formula as well, e.g. "the uncertainty of the average value is estimated to be $Sd[\bar Y] = ...$"